# How to delete a row if every cell in a range contains the same text

Tags: excel, vba

Real project sample here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06911274635715855845

[Sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmtEx.png)

its all in the title,

Lets say i got a doc with ten columns and three hundred rows, A and B contain a number and C to J can contain many words and sometimes the word "Banana".

I'd like to automate a task that goes line by line on the worksheet and deletes the whole row if every cell between C and J contains "Banana", ignoring A and B.

Usually when i have such a question i submit my ideas but i'm quite stumped here from the get go.

Would you be kind enough to help?

Comment: Should the code delete the entire row if columns C to J contain the word "Banana", or if they contain the same word?

Comment: In order not to spoil your homework, I give you a few hints: 1) create an outer loop to traverse all rows from bottom to top. 2) Create an inner loop that traverses the columns C .. J and check if current cell contains the magic word "Banana". 3) exit the inner loop if something else than the magic word is found. 4) Remove the line if all cells had the magic word.

Comment: Oh man thats no homework, I have a 135 columns and 2000+ lines worksheet to comb through every week for job purposes :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the 'homework'. The rest stands.

Comment: Indeed Tom, that was good advice :)

Comment: Please, share somehow your wourbook. Now I am driving... I will look at it whwm I will be home. Theoretically, it should work, without any asaptation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It will delete all rows having the same string in columns C to J ("Banana" inclusive...). It would be very fast. The deletion is done at the end, at once:

**Edited**:

Since, in an worksheet containing tables, the non contiguous entire rows range deletion **is not allowed**, I adapted the code to test if such a table is involved, intersect the collected range to be deleted (its `EntireRow`) with the table and delete the intersected table rows.

Please, test next updated code:

```
Sub testDeleteRowsSameWord()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngDel As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your necessary sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  For i = 1 To lastRow
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("D" & i & ":EA" & i), _
                            sh.Range("D" & i).Value) = 128 Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    If sh.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        If sh.ListObjects.Count > 1 Then MsgBox _
             "This solution works only for a table...": Exit Sub
        Dim Tbl As ListObject, rngInt As Range
        Set Tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)
        Set rngInt = Intersect(Tbl.Range, rngDel.EntireRow)
        If rngInt.Count > 0 Then
            rngInt.Delete xlUp
        Else
            rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
        End If
    Else
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220361/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-how-to-delete-a-row-if-every-cell-in-a-range-co).

Answer (score 0):

They are infinite ways to achieve what you want.
One for example can be something like :

```
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 Dim mBanana As Boolean
 For i = 299 To 0 Step -1 'rows 1 to 300
    mBanana = True
    For j = 0 To 7 'columns C to J
        If Sheets("nameofyoursheet").Range("C1").Offset(i, j).Value <> "Banana" Then
            mBanana = False
        End If
    Next j
    If mBanana = True Then
        Sheets("nameofyoursheet").Range("C1").Offset(i, j).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
 Next i
```

Note that the numbers of rows and columns are hardcoded in the parameters of the `For`, you can easily adapt the code.

Comment: You probably meant to put the line `mBanana = True` within the outer loop, but of before the inner.

Comment: Your code seems like it should work as i easily understand it but it runs and has no visible effect on the sample i posted. I did point to the proper sheet which is "Feuil1" I added a sample i'm trying your code on in the original message

Comment: @CMProjetIDF My bad, this is because the `For j` needs to go from 1 to 7 and not 1 to 8, because column C with an offset of 8 makes column K, not J. I edited my code, try it again and let me know

Comment: Thx Romulax for your answer anyway, I solved it with FaneGuru answer which is even better as my end product doesnt use "Banana" but the minus sign "-", its a perfect all around macro for my use. Have a great day